# Neural Network after first epoch generates NaN values as output, loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, nan

I am trying to set neural network with few layers which will solve simple regression problem which should be 
f(x) = 0,1x or f(x) = 10x

All the code is showed below (generation of data and neural network)

- 4 fully connected layers with ReLu
- loss function RMSE
- learning GradientDescent

problem is after I am running it the output and loss function are turning into NaN value:

- epoch: 0, optimizer: None, loss: inf
- epoch: 1, optimizer: None, loss: nan

And the output layer:
[NaN, NaN, NaN, ..... , NaN]

I am new to tensorflow and I am not sure what I might be doing wrong (badly implement next batch, learning, session implementation)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import numpy

#prepraring input data -> X
learningTestData = numpy.arange(1427456).reshape(1394,1024)

#preparing output data -> f(X) =0.1X
outputData = numpy.arange(1427456).reshape(1394,1024)

xx = outputData.shape
dd = 0
while dd < xx[0]:
    jj = 0
    while jj < xx[1]:
        outputData[dd,jj] = outputData[dd,jj] / 10
        jj += 1
    dd += 1

#preparing the NN
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1024])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1024])

full1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=x, num_outputs=1024, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
full1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(full1)

full2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=full1, num_outputs=5000, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
full2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(full2)

full3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=full2, num_outputs=2500, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
full3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(full3)

full4 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=full3, num_outputs=1024, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
full4 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(full4)


out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=full4, num_outputs=1024, activation_fn=None)


epochs = 20
batch_size = 50
learning_rate = 0.001
batchOffset = 0

# Loss (RMSE) and Optimizer
cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=out)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initializing the variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    e = 0

    while e < epochs:

        #selecting next batch
        sb = batchOffset
        eb = batchOffset+batch_size
        x_batch = learningTestData[sb:eb, :]
        y_batch = outputData[sb:eb, :]

        #learn
        opt = sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch})
        #show RMSE
        c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch})
        print("epoch: {}, optimizer: {}, loss: {}".format(e, opt, c))

        batchOffset += batch_size
        e += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalize your data because your gradients, and as a result `cost`, are exploding. Try to run this code:

```py
learning_rate = 0.00000001
x_batch = learningTestData[:10]
y_batch = outputData[:10]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initializing the variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    opt = sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch})

    c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch})
    print(c) # 531492.3
```

In this case you will get the finite values because the the gradients haven't taken the `cost` to infinity. Use normalized data, reduce learning rate or reduce batch size to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, both learning date adjustment and data preparation helped. When I generated data at random instead incrementally Neural Network Loss function stopped go for inf and started to seek local minima. 

Greatly Thank You!

Comment: Great, glad to hear. Consider pressing on accept my answer button if it helped

Comment: I did, due to be newbie and having low reputation id doesn't show